# Javascript Varialbe in querySelector returns null

Tags: javascript, variables, selectors-api

I'm having trouble getting a variable to work in a querySelector. I have a link like this:

```
<a class="ast-linkto linkto-howitworks">Click to Scroll</a>
```

and further down the page a section like this:

```
<section id="howitworks">
Content here.
</section>
```

This is the part of the function that's causing issues. The console.log works properly, it logs linkToTargetId as `#howitworks` in the console, so that's fine. But I can't do `document.querySelector(linkToTargetId)`, and if I try to wrap that variable in quotes in any manner of way, I get an error that it's not a valid selector. I know I'm missing something simple. `document.querySelector("#howitworks").innerHTML` **does** return the expected result, so it's not like #howitworks doesn't exist.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ast-linkto').forEach(function(item) {
    var regx = new RegExp('\\b' + 'linkto-' + '[^ ]*[ ]?\\b', 'g');
    var linkToTargetClass = item.className.match(regx, '')[0];
    var linkToTargetId = '#' + linkToTargetClass.substring(linkToTargetClass.indexOf("-") + 1);
    console.log(linkToTargetId);

    /* Please let one of these work! */
    console.log(document.querySelector(linkToTargetId).innerHTML);
    console.log(document.querySelector("'"+linkToTargetId+"'").innerHTML);
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ast-linkto').forEach(function(item) {
  var regx = new RegExp('\\b' + 'linkto-' + '[^ ]*[ ]?\\b', 'g');
  var linkToTargetClass = item.className.match(regx, '')[0];
  var linkToTargetId = '#' + linkToTargetClass.substring(linkToTargetClass.indexOf("-") + 1);
  console.log(linkToTargetId);

  /* Please let one of these work! */
  console.log(document.querySelector(linkToTargetId).innerHTML);
  console.log(document.querySelector("'" + linkToTargetId + "'").innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<a class="ast-linkto linkto-howitworks">Click to Scroll</a>

<section id="howitworks">
  Content here.
</section>
```

Comment: I've added a snippet to the question with your code. (I have added the missing closing `})` part). `document.querySelector(linkToTargetId).innerHTML` is working. Is the content in the `section` added asynchronously at a later point after this code runs?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, see here:

https://codepen.io/LyfeLynx/pen/XWjrXVb

Comment: Don't add the extra quotes. The codepen works with  `console.log(document.querySelector(linkToTargetId).innerHTML);`

Comment: Use data attributes. There is no need to have to parse a class to get out text.

Comment: Figured something out, I'll post in another comment. Thanks for the help! @epascarello, I would use data attributes, but sometimes these links are generated from somewhere else and I can add a class, but not a data attribute. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Figured something out:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ast-linkto').forEach(function(item) {
var regx = new RegExp('\\b' + 'linkto-' + '[^ ]*[ ]?\\b', 'g');
var linkToTargetClass = item.className.match(regx, '')[0];
var linkToTargetId = '#' + linkToTargetClass.substring(linkToTargetClass.indexOf("-") + 1);
console.log(linkToTargetId);

    item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        console.log(document.querySelector("" + linkToTargetId + "").innerHTML);
    })
});
```

Clicking on these links is the main idea anyway, so adding the console.log in a click function works!